# How to use observer pattern correctly?

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I am learning design patterns. But when I studied observer pattern, a question came to my mind.

A typically observer pattern has following compenents:

- Subject: An object holds some information acquired by Observer.
- Observer: The object that monitors Subject. When some events happen, subject will inform observer.

My question is why it is **Subject's** duty to decide when to call observer. In my site, I think the condition should be chosen by observer.

Take the water heater as a simple example. A temperature monitor(observer) will alert, when the temperature is up to 95. So I can use the following code to describe this model.

```
namespace Heater
{
     public class Heater{   // subject
          private int temperature;
          public delegate void BoilHandler(int para);
          public event BoilHandler BoilEvent;

          public void BoilWater(){
               for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++)
               {
                    temperature = i;
                    if(temperature > 95){   //decide when to inform observer
                         BoilEvent(temperature);
                    }
               }
          }
     }

     public class Alarm{    // observer
          public void MakeAlert(int param){
               Console.WriteLine("ALarm: UP TO 95, NOW is {0}", param);
          }
     }
}
```

So in observer pattern, I seperate Alarm from Heater. The implement of alarm depends on customer. But when I want to change the alarming threshold, I must change the code in class Heater rather than class Alarm.

Comment: This is too broad. The actual implementation depends on how close you'd like your model to reflect reality. For example we could create a design like this: Person (obj1) who is observing the heater's (obj2) gauge (obj3) that displays water's (obj4) temperature with eyes (obj5) that sends signal to brain (obj6) and so on and so on... So think of this implementation of Observer as a simplified picture more or less virtually reflecting things that exist in real world.

Comment: In this scheme gauge will observe the heater and raise an event which will be consumed by eyes and propagated to the brain that will decide that the water had indeed boiled. But to simplify all of that we can basically say:"Heater has raised event that its water has boiled"